# How to do CAS 5.3.2 authenticate with AD using userPassword

Tags: active-directory, single-sign-on, cas

I have a Active Directory storage which hold password in field `userPassword`.
I used CAS 5.3.2 to do authenticate with AD, here's my configs:

```
    # Interesting part for Active Directory:
cas.authn.ldap[0].type=AD
cas.authn.ldap[0].ldapUrl=ldap://85.2.58.119:389

cas.authn.ldap[0].useSsl=false
cas.authn.ldap[0].useStartTls=false
cas.authn.ldap[0].connectTimeout=5000

cas.authn.ldap[0].baseDn=OU=User Account,OU=CAS,DC=liferayadmin,DC=net
cas.authn.ldap[0].userFilter=cn={user}
cas.authn.ldap[0].subtreeSearch=true

# AD manager user like someone@company.com
cas.authn.ldap[0].bindDn=cn=casAdmin,OU=User Account,OU=CAS,cn=users,dc=liferayadmin,dc=net
cas.authn.ldap[0].bindCredential=password
cas.authn.ldap[0].dnFormat=%s@liferayadmin.net

cas.authn.ldap[0].principalAttributeId=cn
cas.authn.ldap[0].principalAttributePassword=
cas.authn.ldap[0].principalAttributeList=sAMAccountName,sn,cn,givenName,displayName

cas.authn.ldap[0].failFast=false

# Default values:
cas.authn.ldap[0].minPoolSize=3
cas.authn.ldap[0].maxPoolSize=10
cas.authn.ldap[0].validateOnCheckout=true
cas.authn.ldap[0].validatePeriodically=true
cas.authn.ldap[0].validatePeriod=600
cas.authn.ldap[0].idleTime=5000
cas.authn.ldap[0].prunePeriod=5000
cas.authn.ldap[0].blockWaitTime=5000
```

It return failed authentication. Someone said that AD use another field to check password, but I can use this field 'userPassword' only.

How can I authenticate with AD using this field?

How can I check what is root cause of `fail autheticate`?(cannot connect AD / wrong bindCredential / other exceptions ...).

And if possible, pls look at my configs and find if I have some mistake.
Thanks!